# Removing URL from a URL classloader

Tags: java, classloader

Is there any way to remove the URL from a URLClassloader?

If suppose we removed the URL from classloader what all possible problems can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to remove the URL from a URLClassloader?

AFAIK, no.

> If suppose we removed the URL from classloader what all possible problems can happen?

Well, for a start it can break code that relies on being able to dynamically load classes and resources.  It is also possible this kind of thing could be used to break security sandboxes.

Why are you considering doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to remove the URL
>   from a URLClassloader?

No.

> If suppose we removed the URL from
>   classloader what all possible problems
>   can happen?

As you can't the question is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `URL`s with `URLStreamHandler`s which shutdown, if you were desperate. That may not affect load classes and resources from already open Jar files.

I don't see a particular problem with this. Unlike `addURL` where a class may not be on the set of URLs when first asked for, and cannot be subsequently added.